# Bundling in Recyclerview- Android

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, material-design

I want to create a simple view like this. (red circle)

[image]

I searched on internet for **Bundling in Recyclerview** but I could not find any resources.

Can anyone tell me the name of this view or share any tutorial resources.

Can someone share an example of how to do it. Or any Tutorials on how to get this view . - Bounty question

Answer (score 6):

In recyclerview you can do this with item decoration.

> An ItemDecoration allows the application to add a special drawing and
>   layout offset to specific item views from the adapter's data set. This
>   can be useful for drawing dividers between items, highlights, visual
>   grouping boundaries and more.
>
> All ItemDecorations are drawn in the order they were added, before the
>   item views (in onDraw()) and after the items (in onDrawOver(Canvas,
>   RecyclerView, RecyclerView.State).

refer [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemDecoration.html)

or

> you can design a custom layout and inflate it using getViewByType in
>   viewholder

Answer (score -1):

I think you better to follow this videos, i am sure my side this videos gives you a perfect idea on **Android Recyclerview** and also provide a solution for problem.

Please follow this youtube link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XhbsNO2_oDI

Comment: This video is just about a normal recyclerview.

Comment: What you want coding for that one

Answer (score -2):

ItemDecorator from example below doesn't suite you. Try to use Expandable Listview, which helps you to adjust list, when user tap on image below list item, and expand size for another item, for example, chat messages in your image.

**[Use This Example!](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/)**

Comment: listview is no-more supported on android

Comment: @SathyaBaman It's ExpandableListView and he doesn't deprecated! https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html